# Run a command whenever Unicorn starts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, unicorn

I'm currently working on a Digital Ocean instance with a Rails server with Unicorn on Ubuntu.  I've gotten everything running, except for one thing.

There is a gem I'm using called delayed jobs, and it needs to start as a daemon to function correctly whenever the server restarts.  The problem is that it seems like the gem has *very* many different ways of starting, many of which aren't supported with my current version.  So, I thought instead of searching through piles of inapplicable docs, I could just start it up with a shell command that I know works.

I'm not using anything like Capistrano - so what would the best way of running a command-line script when Unicorn starts be?  I have to run

```
cd /home/rails/ 
RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job start
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Foreman](http://ddollar.github.io/foreman/) gem.

With that, you can easily start your applications all in one go by executing `foreman start`. You will need a configuration file called `Procfile`.

This is a sample of my `Procfile`. Here, I'm using it to run Unicorn, MailCatcher, and Sidekiq.

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
mailcatcher: ruby -rbundler/setup -e "Bundler.clean_exec('mailcatcher --foreground --ip=0.0.0.0')"
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -C ./config/sidekiq.yml
```

In your case, it would be something like this:

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
worker: bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

Reference: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job

Comment: Wouldn't this require manually starting the server, though?  I already have unicorn starting automatically.